# How can I specify ports using Go remote import paths?

Tags: git, go

given I have a private (corporate self-hosted) git repository which listens on on another but the default http-port. (For example 6655)

The full repository-url to my golang-library would be:

```
http://internal-git.corporate-domain.com:6655/~myuser/golang-lib.git
```

I tried importing this like so:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "internal-git.corporate-domain.com:6655/~myuser/golang-lib.git"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"

)
```

Documentation [here](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths) and [here](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#remote) is not explicit about that.

When I try to compile the code above I get:

```
C:\Users\myuser\gopath\src\myuser\golang-project>go get
can't load package: package myuser/golang-project:
main.go:7:2: invalid import path: "internal-git.corporate-domain.com:6655/~myuser/golang-lib.git"
```

Comment: You clone them yourself into your GOPATH

Comment: A directory name cannot contain `:` character on Windows.

Comment: Also `~` in package import path is not supported in Go 1.5 or earlier. Go 1.6 fixes this as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to change your .gitconfig to work with ports.

```
[url "git@internal-git.corporate-domain.com:6655"]
  insteadOf = git://internal-git.corporate-domain.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Like a previous comment said you probably want to clone the *Git* repository into your `$GOPATH` (`%GOPATH%` for *Windows*) directory.

Per your example the `clone` command would look like:

```
git clone internal-git.corporate-domain.com:6655/~myuser/golang-lib.git $GOPATH/corporate-domain.com/golang-lib
```

And your import in *Go* source files would look like:

```
import "corporate-domain.com/golang-lib"
```