# Import path with colons in Golang

Tags: git, go, import

I have local private repository (gitlab) with hostname https://git.local.com:1234/

Also I have several packages in my golang project

Project structure looks like:

```
// my_project/main.go
package main

import (
    "git.local.com:1234/my_project/notMainPackage"
)

func main() {
    //....
}

// my_project/notMainPackage/notMainPackage.go
package notMainPackage

func SomeFunc() {

}
```

The problem is that I should use colons in my import path to be able run `go get` and `go build` comands, but, when import path contains colon, I get error

`invalid import path: "git.local.com:1234/my_project/notMainPackage"`

I can't change host of gitlab sever.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I specify ports using Go remote import paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922929/how-can-i-specify-ports-using-go-remote-import-paths)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the suggestion in comment,

do

```
git clone git.local.com:1234/my_project/notMainPackage
```

so the git project loads on to your gopath and

just use it like below,

```
// my_project/main.go
package main

import (
    "my_project/notMainPackage"
)

func main() {
    //....
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Yes, it helps, but I don't think this is a good solution. My project could be have another dependencies from internal repository (currently not), and I will have load it manualy, using "git clone"